# Execute SQL Task in SSIS - OLEDB Vs Ado.Net connection which one is better?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

I am going to run a stored procedure which updates 3 tables of 60 million records each and all in same server. I am currently using OLEDB connection instead of ADO.Net connection.

Points:

> Currently It is running for 21 minutes in management studio.
>
> If i use OLEDB connection it runs in 32 minutes
>
> If is use ADO.net connection it runs for 48 minutes

Which connection manager I need to use to get around 21 minutes time frame? Any best practices on this? I am using SQL Server 2016 and SSIS 2016.

Comment: Typically OLEDB works best I have found for my applications. The reason why it is taking so long is because it has to go through the SSIS agent to connect to the server where is SSMS gives you a direct connection to the server. Have you tried setting up a job in the server without SSIS.

Comment: Job by sql task is also taking similar ~21 minutes. Even I am finding OLEDB  is better bet... but I am still profiling on how both works, trying to understand that better so that I can use the appropriate tasks...

Comment: I tried to use sql profiler to checkout any difference. but nothing found on my sample data.

Comment: There is a difference in ADO.net which acts like a cursor and hence it it is very slow if i handle more than 30 millions of records... I do not see much difference if it is <25 millions of records. So for >30million records I found OLEDB as better bet..

Answer (score 0):

How do you implement the update operation? if you use OLEDB command, it takes time. My suggestion is you can try parallel processing. Instead of doing it all in one Dataflow task. You can use batch processing and make several DFT run at the same time. It will shrink the time dramatically.